# python threaded port scanner

Tags: python, multithreading

When my app has gone through all the ports it should print "done." But it's not. This is what I have:

```
import time
import socket
import threading
from queue import Queue

printLock = threading.Lock()

q = Queue()

target = input("Enter Ip: ")

def portscan(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
       con = s.connect((target,port))
       with printLock:
          print("port",port,"open")
       con.close()
    except:
       pass

def threader():
   while True:
      worker = q.get()
      portscan(worker)
      q.task_done()

for x in range(10000):
   t = threading.Thread(target = threader)
   t.daemon = True
   t.start()

for worker in range(1,101):
   q.put(worker)

q.join()

print("done")
```

Comment: Questions asking "why isn't my code working" are off-topic. You should edit your question to show what your app *is* doing, and where you're stuck. (note: I edited your question to make it more straightforward to read)

Comment: It prints `"done"` for me (python 3.5), only problem I detected was that you imported `from queue` with a lower Q.